# How can I add an active class when the user scrolls to a section with smooth scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I am building a simple 1 page website & using JQuery to change the color of the nav links at the page. I have implemented smooth scroll which goes to each anchor nicely. I have also implemented a feature which allows the user to scroll down the page & the active class gets applied to the anchors in the nav changing the color.

Things are working almost correctly...except:
When you click on a nav link the active class is not being applied to the correct link.

So far I have tried to change the way the classes are being applied & also the names to direct IDs but its still not behaving perfect. Theres clearly something incorrect happening with `$('.nav li').eq(i).find('a').addClass('active');`

Can anyone suggest how I can fix this?

Heres the CP with the html:
https://codepen.io/nolimit966/pen/aboqvOP

Thank you

JS:

```
    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
        var WindowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('section').each(function(i){
            if(WindowTop > $(this).offset().top - 50 && 
               WindowTop < $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight(true)
              ){
                $('.nav > li > a').removeClass('active');
     $('.nav li').eq(i).find('a').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
          $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
              }
            }
          });
        });,
```

HTML:

````
        <h1>Test</h1>
     </header>
     <nav id="c-primary-nav__list-1" class="c-primary-nav__list">
        <ul class="nav">
           <li class="c-primary-nav__item">
              <a class="c-primary-nav__link" href="#about">About</a>
           </li>
           <li class="c-primary-nav__item">
              <a class="c-primary-nav__link active" href="#reservations">Reservations</a>
           </li>
           <li class="c-primary-nav__item">
              <a class="c-primary-nav__link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
           </li>
           <li class="c-primary-nav__item">
              <a class="c-primary-nav__link" href="#offers">Offers</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="c-primary-nav__details">
        </div>
     </nav>
     <div class="l-content-blocks">
        <div class="l-content-blocks__wrapper">
           <section class="cb-about" id="about">
              <div class="cb-about__wrapper">
                 <div class="cb-about__container">
                    <div class="cb-about__intro-wrapper">
                       <h1 class="cb-about__h1" data-aos="fade-up">About </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cb-about__image-showcase">
                       <div data-aos="fade-up" class="cb-about__showcase-item cb-about__showcase-item--image">
                          <div class="c-media" data-push-to-gallery-modal="">
                             </p>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div data-aos="fade-up" class="cb-about__showcase-item cb-about__showcase-item--image">
                          <div class="c-media" data-push-to-gallery-modal="">
                             <p class="c-media__caption">Caption Header <em>Caption Copy</em>
                             </p>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="cb-about__showcase-item cb-about__showcase-item--description">
                          <p data-aos="fade-up" class="cb-about__description">Description section 3 </p>
                       </div>
                       <div data-aos="fade-up" class="cb-about__showcase-item cb-about__showcase-item--image">
                          <div class="c-media" data-push-to-gallery-modal="">
                             <p class="c-media__caption">Caption Header <em>Caption copy</em>
                             </p>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cb-about__gallery-button-wrapper">
                       <div class="c-button ">
                          <a class="c-button__link" href="#" target="" data-toggle="c-modal"
                             data-target="#gallery-modal">Gallery CTA text</a>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </section>
           <section class="cb-our-menus" id="menus">
              <div class="cb-our-menus__wrapper">
                 <div class="cb-our-menus__container">
                    <div class="cb-our-menus__intro-wrapper">
                       <h1 class="cb-our-menus__h1">Our Menus</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cb-our-menus__button-grid">
                       <div class="cb-our-menus__button-item">
                       </div>
                       <div class="cb-our-menus__button-item">
                       </div>
                       <div class="cb-our-menus__button-item">
                       </div>
                       <div class="cb-our-menus__button-item">
                       </div>
                       <div class="cb-our-menus__button-item">
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </section>
           <section class="cb-offers" id="offers">
              <div class="cb-offers__wrapper">
                 <div class="cb-offers__container">
                    <h1 class="cb-offers__h1">Offer Option Header</h1>
                    <p class="cb-offers__intro intro">Something cool</p>
                    <div class="cb-offers__button-grid">
                       <div class="cb-offers__button-item">
                       </div>
                       <div class="cb-offers__button-item">
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cb-offers__image-wrapper">
                       <div class="c-media" data-push-to-gallery-modal="">
                          <p class="c-media__caption">Caption Title <em>Caption Description</em>
                          </p>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </section>
           <section class="cb-reservations" id="reservations">
              <div class="cb-reservations__wrapper">
                 <div class="cb-reservations__container">
                    <h1 class="cb-reservations__h1">Reservations</h1>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </section>
           <section class="cb-contact" id="contact">
              <div class="cb-contact__wrapper">
                 <div class="cb-contact__container">
                    Contact info here
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="cb-contact__map-wrapper">
              </div>
           </section>
           <section class="cb-reservations" id="reservations">
              <div class="cb-reservations__wrapper">
                 <div class="cb-reservations__container">
                    <h1 class="cb-reservations__h1">fdsfdsf</h1>
                    <p class="cb-reservations__booking-description">fdsfsdfds</p>
                    <div class="cb-reservations__button-wrapper cb-reservations__button-wrapper--book">
                       <div class="c-button ">
                          <a class="c-button__link highlight"
                             target="">Book Now</a>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </section>
        </div>
        <section class="cb-newsletter">
           <div class="cb-newsletter__wrapper">
              <div class="cb-newsletter__container">
                 <h1 class="cb-newsletter__h1"> Newsletter</h1>
              </div>
           </div>
        </section>
        <section class="cb-signature-dishes">
           <div class="cb-signature-dishes__wrapper">
              <div class="cb-signature-dishes__container">
                 <h1 class="cb-signature-dishes__h1"> Dishes</h1>
              </div>
           </div>
        </section>
     </div>
     <footer>
        &copy;2019 Footer
     </footer>```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a lib to simplify your implementation:

https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear

All your javascript would look like this:

```
        var addClassOnScroll = function () {
            $('section[id]').each(function (index, elem) {
                if($(elem).is(':appeared')) {
                    const elemId = $(elem).attr('id');
                    $("nav ul li a.active").removeClass('active');
                    $("nav ul li a[href='#" + elemId + "']").addClass('active');
                }
            });
        };

        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            addClassOnScroll();
        });
```

**Option without lib:**

```
 var addClassOnScroll = function () {
            var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            $('section[id]').each(function (index, elem) {
                var offsetTop = $(elem).offset().top;
                var outerHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);

                if( windowTop > (offsetTop - 50) && windowTop < ( offsetTop + outerHeight)) {
                    var elemId = $(elem).attr('id');
                    $("nav ul li a.active").removeClass('active');
                    $("nav ul li a[href='#" + elemId + "']").addClass('active');
                }
            });
        };

        $(function () {
            $(window).on('scroll', function () {
                addClassOnScroll();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I cant/dont want to use another library as the page already uses jQuery. Also the scroll viewport functionality is working fine. Its just the click thats not changing colour correctly.

Comment: Added option without lib

Comment: That is absolutely perfect. Thank you very very much!! The fact you moved the add class into its own function is much neater than me trying to repeat myself on the version i was working on.

Comment: You can move var windowTop to the beginning of the function, I edited the answer